# C# Remote Process username and password incorrect

Tags: c#

Hello i'm try to get procceses to Remote Computer in my LAN network , i set all of the property good i know username and password but when i try to connect it give back to me

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The user name or password is incorrect;

i type the right Username and Password with administrative rights what do u think ?

That is my code

```
onst string file = "cmd.exe";

        var sspw = new SecureString();

        foreach (var c in "password")
            sspw.AppendChar(c);

        var proc = new Process();

        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);

        proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetFileName(file);

        proc.StartInfo.Domain = "REMOTEPC";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
        proc.StartInfo.UserName = "username";
        proc.StartInfo.Password = sspw;
        proc.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = false;
        proc.Start();
```

Comment: Is the computer part of a domain? So do you need to include the domain name in the username like `domain\username` ?

Comment: Yes it is i try before posting question this way that u told but same result.

Comment: I think you have a group policy issue.  Is the remove computer in the same user group as the local computer?  The User Group isn't allowing the remote login.  Is Remote logins enabled on the remote computer?

Comment: I think yes i enable everything , can u be more specified when or what to enable what do u thing ?

Comment: You need to modify the user account table to add computer/users to the same group(s).  Do you have network admin privileges on both computers?  You may need admin support.